# Required 'compute.regions.get' permission for 'projects/$project_id/regions/us-central1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm pretty new on Google cloud, and I'm trying to use GCloud command line, and I faced the following problem

```
Error: Forbidden access to resources.
Raw response:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Required 'compute.regions.get' permission for 'projects/$project_id/regions/us-central1'"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Required 'compute.regions.get' permission for 'projects/$project_id/regions/us-central1'"
 }
}
```

Can someone help?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot your issue, please try following:

1. Where are you running the command: Cloud Shell, Local environment?
   If it is local environment, try [Cloud Shell instead](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quickstart).
2. Check that you are using the latest version of [gcloud sdk 262](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update).
3. Did you properly [initialize gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/init)?
4. Can you confirm that you have [appropriate role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_role_definitions) to run the command, like editior/owner?
5. Check if you are using that same [location for your products](https://cloud.google.com/docs/geography-and-regions)
6. If above steps don't work, can you share your complete gcloud command to have more context?

Comment: Thanks, Pawel, I will try the options and let you know.

Comment: I followed your tips, and I found them useful, I have removed everything and started from scratch based on these points, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I see where the problem is! When I created the storage, I put the region as "Asia". When I configured it via `gcloud init`, I put it as "us-central1-a". The "Permission denied" means in this context, I have no permission to access another server region. It is misleading in terms of thinking out the cloud scope. However, the Pawel's answer is more comprehensive, and it is a very good start to lead you to the correct direction.